# Propositional logic: Natural deduction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, computer-science

Is the first solution valid? If not, can someone explain to me why the first solution is not valid but the second one is? Both claim that p and not p is true though?

$\lnot p \to p \vdash p$

$1 \hspace{1cm}   \lnot p \to  p \hspace{1cm}  premise$

$\hspace{1cm} 2 \hspace{1cm}    \lnot p  \hspace{1cm}   Assumption$

$\hspace{1cm} 3 \hspace{1cm}    p  \hspace{1cm}   \to e \phantom{B}  1,2$

$4  \hspace{1cm}    p \hspace{1cm}  \to e \phantom{B} 2-3 $

Or

$1 \hspace{1cm}   \lnot p \to  p \hspace{1cm}  premise$

$\hspace{1cm} 2 \hspace{1cm}    \lnot p  \hspace{1cm}   Assumption$

$\hspace{1cm} 3 \hspace{1cm}    p  \hspace{1cm}   \to e\phantom{BC} 1,2$

$\hspace{1cm} 4 \hspace{1cm}    \perp  \hspace{1cm}  \lnot e \phantom{B} 2,3$

$5 \hspace{1cm}   \lnot \lnot   \hspace{1cm}  \lnot i 2-4$

$6 \hspace{1cm}       p          \hspace{1cm} \lnot \lnot e \phantom{B}5 \phantom{B}  (PBC \phantom{B} 2-4)    $

Comment: The first one is incorrect, because you need $\neg p$ to eliminate the implication.